# Induction proof concerning a sum of binomial coefficients: $\sum_{j=m}^n\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm looking for a proof of this identity but where j=m not j=0

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients_over_Upper_Index

$$\sum_{j=m}^n\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}$$

Comment: To clarify what you mean: you want a proof of 
$$\sum_{j=m}^n\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}$$
correct?

Comment: (-1) ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you are looking for the proof of the identity: $$ \sum_{j=m}^n\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}$$

This is actually known as the Hockey-Stick Identity.You can find different methods of proving this in [this page](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity).

**Please note** that there are many applications of the hockey stick identity and all the combinatorial identities you may encounter, this is the one most worth remembering.  It 
makes a lot of apparently hard problems very easy.

Comment: Any idea why it's called the hockey stick identity?

Comment: @Alex: when you go to the URL FoolForMath provided, it shows a picture with the above identity represented on Pascal's triangle, on which the relevant numbers form a 'hockey stick'.

Comment: @Gerben: Oh, I guess that's a little hockey stick like. Neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  what is $\binom{2}{4}$?  what is $\binom{n-1}{n}?$