# How can I simplify $1\times 2 + 2 \times 3 + .. + (n-1) \times n$ progression?

Tags: summation

I have a progression that goes like this:

$$1\times 2 + 2 \times 3 + .. + (n-1) \times n$$
Is there a way I can simplify it?

Comment: $2\binom n3{}{}{}{}$

Comment: [Sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers - induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376284/sum-of-the-first-n-triangular-numbers-induction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\,(i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i$$ which are quite standard summations. For the first one $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\frac{1}{6} (n-1) n (2 n-1)$$ and for the second $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n$$ Add them together and simplify (noticing some nice factorizations).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You have
$$
(n^3-n)-\left((n-1)^3-(n-1)\right)=3\times(n-1)\times n
$$ and the sum is **telescoping**.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get from my progression to the left expression?

Comment: Yes, I recalled that $(n-1)^3=n^3-3n^2+3n-1$ giving $n^3-(n-1)^3=3\times (n-1)n+1$, then I obtained the given identity. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your explanation still didn't show anything that looked like my series.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
\begin{align*}
1\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 3 + \dotsb + (n-1)\cdot n
&= 1\cdot(1+1) + 2\cdot(2+1) + \dotsb + (n-1)\cdot((n-1)+1) \\
&= 1^2 + 1 + 2^2 + 2 + \dotsb + (n-1)^2 + (n-1) \\
&= (1^2+2^2+\dotsb+(n-1)^2) + (1+2+\dotsb+(n-1))
\end{align*}
Both of those sums have well-known closed forms; see [here](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-introduction), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have $T_r=r(r+1)$ which you can write as
$$T_r=\frac{r(r+1)\{(r+2)-(r-1)\}}{(r+2)-(r-1)}$$
$$T_r=\frac{1}{3}\{r(r+1)(r+2)-(r-1)r(r+1)\}$$
And there you have your telescoping series. On adding up all terms you will find 
$$S_{n-1}=\frac{1}{3}(n-1)n(n+1)$$