# Proof of $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}=1+3+6+10...$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Proof of title(implies proof of this type of sequence) Also how does this link to further proofs of $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}$ etc. and the proof of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: Induction??????

Comment: See also [Sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers - induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376284) and the posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/376284). (And probably there are some other posts about the same sum, this was one I was able to find relatively quickly.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Answer (score 2):

These are just [Hockey-sticky identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).
Left side is precisely ${n}\choose{3}$, right side is $\sum {{n-1}\choose{2}}$
and the identity itself is easily deduced from recursive definition of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{r(r+1)}2=\dfrac12\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+\dfrac12\sum_{r=1}^nr$$

Now use [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/).

Comment: Observe that $$3-1=2,6-3=3,10-6=4$$ etc.  So, the $r$th term of $1,3,6,10$ will be $$1+2+3+4+\cdots+r=?$$