# Combinatorial approach to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \binom{i+r-1}i$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{i+r-1}{i}$$

I want to solve above sum combinatorially.

Comment: I need a hint to start.

Comment: Using $\binom{i+r-1}i=\binom{i+r-1}{r-1}$, isn't this the same sum as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74844/induction-proof-concerning-a-sum-of-binomial-coefficients)?

Comment: See [$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The value of ${i+r-1\choose i}+{i+r-1\choose i-1}={i+r\choose i}$  So the first couple terms look like

$${r\choose 1}+{r\choose 0}-{r\choose 0}+{r+1\choose 2}+{r+2\choose 3}+\cdots$$

$$=-{r\choose 0}+{r+1\choose 1}+{r+1\choose 2}+{r+2\choose 3}+\cdots$$

$$=-{r\choose 0}+{r+2\choose 2}+{r+2\choose 3}+\cdots$$

Can you take it from here?  Note that $-{r\choose 0}=-1$ is in place to offset the addition of ${r\choose 0}$ in the first sum above.

Comment: after $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  {i+r \choose i}$-
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  {i+r-1 \choose i-1}$ , how we can simplify terms? and what is $  {r \choose 1}$?

Comment: No, use the specific terms I mention in my hint and add them directly by the definition of the values given.  For example, ${r\choose 1}={r!\over 1!(r-1)!}$ as should be expected.

Comment: I don't know your hint,and I need a analysis.if you can help me more.

Comment: Expanded the hint.  What do you think now?

Comment: final answer is :$\ {n+r-1 \choose n}$-1??

Comment: No, final answer is ${n+r\choose n}-1$.  The last term to be added is $n+r-1\choose n$.

Comment: ok, thanks abiessu.