# Show $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n+1}{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

My question is:

show $$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n+1}{m}$$
$$n\geq m\geq 1$$
I tried to do this via induction and failed. there has to be another way of doing this.

We could either explain combinatorically that we are counting the same thing in 2 different ways, in this sense, we are counting the number of ways to choose $m$ elements from a set with $n+1$ elements.

Or we could try like me to prove it algebraically, both ways are valid...I'd like some help, or a push in the right direction.

Comment: maybe his could help

$\binom{n+1}{m}=\binom{n}{m}+\binom{n}{m-1}$

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is (in a different form) the same identity as in the following questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74844/induction-proof-concerning-a-sum-of-binomial-coefficients
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544503/combinatorial-approach-to-sum-limits-i-1n-binomir-1i
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205031/trying-to-prove-that-p-prime-divides-binomp-1k-binomp-2k-1-cdo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The right side counts the number of ways to pick $m$ elements out of $n+1$.

For the left: partition the $m$-element subsets of $n+1$ based on the highest element that is NOT included in the subset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. You want me to partition the big set (of $n+1$ elements) to different sets of $m$ elements based on the highest element that isn't in the subset? I don't follow.

Comment: @OriaGruber Not at all.  I want you to partition _the collection of $m$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$_ based on the highest absent element.  Then the size of the full collection is the sum of the size of these parts...

Comment: if the highest element that is not used is $n-k$, then all the elements $\{n-k+1,...n+1\}$ are used. That's $k+1$ elements. that means that from the set $\{1,2,...n-k-1\}$ we use only $m-(k+1)$ elements

Comment: @OriaGruber Right.  Now, to fix things a little bit, say that the highest element not used is $n+1-k$.  Then $k$ is between $0$ (meaning that we don't use element $n+1$) and $m$ (meaning that we use all $m$ elements greater than $n+1-m$, and no others).  For a given value of $k$, we use elements $n+1-k+1,\ldots,n+1$ ($k$ total), don't use element $n+1-k$, and have to use $m-k$ from $\{1,2,\ldots,n-k\}$.  So...

Comment: yeah I understand now :) if $n-k$ is the largest value not used, that means $\{n-k+1,...,n+1\}$ are all used and there's no choice involved. However, now we need to choose $m-(k+1)$ elements from $\{1,2,...,n-k-1\}$ and for that I have $\binom{n-k-1}{m-k-1}$ options. since we took arbitrary such highest absent value, the sum of all of those (for all absent values) is the number of ways to choose m out of n+1.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. Just 2 last questions for you :D how did you know what the left side represents? Because I have more questions like this, I wont come here for help every time. And is there an algebraic solution?

Comment: @OriaGruber The big thought is this: on the right side, for each $k$, we've reduced the problem of choosing $m$ out of $n+1$ to the problem of choosing $m-k$ out of $n-k$.  So, the question is really: how can you break the problem apart (so that there's no overlap!) in such a way that given $k$, we already know that exactly $k$ out of a given set of $k+1$ elements are used?  I'm sure there's an algebraic solution, but I think that combinatorial arguments are much more instructive.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been suggested, this is nothing else than [Pascal's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) applied recursively *m* times:

$${n+1\choose m}=\underbrace{n\choose m}_{k=0}+{n\choose m-1}=\underbrace{{n\choose m}+{n-1\choose m-1}}_{\begin{align}\text{The first terms of our series,}\\\text{for k=0 and k=1}\quad\end{align}}+{n-1\choose m-2}=\ldots=\sum_{k=0}^m{n-k\choose m-k}$$

Comment: @barto: Same here. I suspect the site is currently undergoing some technical difficulties.

Comment: @barto: Better now ?