# Next term of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Whats the logic behind the series :
0,1,7,28,84,210,426,924 and so on..

As I figured it, it is basically sum of consecutive terms of (5+r)Cr where r range from 0 to whatever term I need to find(my requirement is 999998). I need to calculate this series till 10^6 which will certainly overflow by this method. Any other logic or technique?

Comment: Are you attempting to calculate the entire factorials? If so, why not get the prime factorizations and cancel everything off?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644106/show-sum-k-0m-binomn-km-k-binomn1m

Comment: From 1, multiply by 7/1, 8/2, 9/3, 10/4, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that $426$ is a mistake. If we have $462$ instead of $426$, then this sequence could be the following.

$$a_n= \binom{n+4}{6}$$

From $n=1$ to $15$ it gives the following sequence ([A000579](http://oeis.org/A000579)):

$$0, 1, 7, 28, 84, 210, 462, 924, 1716, 3003, 5005, 8008, 12376, 18564, 27132.$$

You could find other possible solutions at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C7%2C28%2C84%2C210).

$$a_{999998} = \binom{999998+4}{6} = 1388884722215277798611116666650000.$$

You can calculate the whole sequence in an arbitrary range for example with *[Maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software))*, with this code:

```
seq(binomial(n+4,6),n=1..1000);
```

This sample code gives you the sequence in the range $n=1$ to $1000$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $f(r)=r(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)(r-4)(r-5)$, note that 
$$(r+5)(r+4)(r+3)(r+2)(r+1)$$$$=\frac{1}{6}\{(r+6)(r+5)(r+4)(r+3)(r+2)(r+1)-(r+5)(r+4)(r+3)(r+2)(r+1)r\}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\{f(r+6)-f(r+5)\}.$$

So, we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{r+5}{r}&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{r+5}{5}\\&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{(r+5)(r+4)(r+3)(r+2)(r+1)}{5!}\\&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{f(r+6)-f(r+5)}{6\times 5!}\\&=\frac{1}{6!}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\{f(r+6)-f(r+5)\}\\&=\frac{1}{720}\{(f(6)-f(5))+(f(7)-f(6))+\cdots+(f(n+6)-f(n+5))\}\\&=\frac{1}{720}(f(n+6)-f(5))\\&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)}{720}\\&=\binom{n+6}{6}=b_n.\end{align}$$

(Note that $b_0=1,b_1=7,b_3=84,\cdots$.)

P.S. As user153012 pointed in his/her comment, your sequence can be also represented as
$$\binom{n+5}{6}\ \ \ (n=0,1,2,\cdots).$$

Comment: And it is $\binom{n+5}{6}$.

Comment: @user153012: $\binom{n+6}{6}$, isn't it?

Comment: If you run the index from $1$ then you're right, if from $0$ then my solution is the correct. But okay. It is all the same.

Comment: @user153012: Oh, I got what you mean. thank you.