# Combinatorics Summation Formula

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Can anybody please tell me the summation formula for:

$$\sum_{i=1}^NC(k+i-1, i) = ?$$

Where ' k ' is some constant.
Here C(x, y) stands for Combinatorics formula e.g. C(12, 6) = 924.

Comment: Do you mean the binominal $\dbinom{k+i-1}{i}$?

Comment: See [$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451)