# Summation of Binomial Coffecient

Tags: combinatorics, summation

What will be the summation of this Series

$$\binom{10}{1} + \binom{11}{2} + \binom{12}{3} +\cdots+\binom{10+n}{n+1}$$

Comment: See [$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451)

Comment: Note that this is the same as $$\binom {10}9+\binom{11}9+\binom{12}9+\cdots+\binom{10+n}9$$ or $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{r+10}9$$ or $$\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}\binom{r+9}9$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add $\dbinom{10}0$ to your sum and apply successively the Pascal's identity you have:
$$\dbinom{n}k+\dbinom{n}{k+1}=\dbinom{n+1}{k+1}$$ you will get:

$$\underbrace{\binom{10}{0} + \binom{10}{1}}_{\dbinom{11}{1}} + \binom{11}{2} +\cdots+\binom{10+n}{n+1}$$

and again $\dbinom{11}{1}$ will concel with $\dbinom{11}{1}$ to get $\dbinom{12}{2}$ and so on$\cdots$. The sum equals in the end:
$$\binom{11+n}{n+1}-\binom{10}{0}=\binom{11+n}{10}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

People keep asking the same question over and over these days, maybe it is time to add an answer as a reference for forthcoming  identical questions.

It is straightforward to prove by induction that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{K}\binom{n+k}{n}=\binom{n+K+1}{n+1}\tag{1}$$
hence your sum equals:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{9+k}{9}=\binom{11+n}{10}-1.\tag{2}$$