# About the computation of the limit $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + x^{99}}{x^{100}} $

Tags: limits, fake-proofs

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948506/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-frac199-299-cdots-n99n100) and I don't understand why I can't do this:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1^{99} + 2^{99} + \cdots + x^{99}}{x^{100}} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1^{99}}{x^{100}} + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^{99}}{x^{100}} + \cdots + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{99}}{x^{100}} \\ 
 &= 0 + 0 + \cdots + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \\
 &= 0
\end{align*}

I know that isn't the correct answer but I want to know why it's not. Why does it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because you're incorrectly using the linearity of limits. You can split a limit over a fixed sum, but the sum you're examining expands with $x$. Just like Riemann sum does (hint, hint!).

Comment: What do you mean by "the sum you're examining expands with $x$"?

Comment: I mean that the number of terms in the sum depends on $x$. You can distribute the limit over a sum with a fixed number of terms, not over a sum where the number of terms increases with $x$. The classic example of where this doesn't work is Riemann sums: you are looking at a sum of areas of rectangles, each of which individually go to $0$, but overall, the limit of the Riemann sums will not necessarily be $0$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280838/finding-limits-using-definite-integrals-lim-n-to-infty-sumn-k-1-frack4/1280865?noredirect=1#comment2741297_1280865