# How to simplify this triple summation

Tags: summation

I am trying to calculate the following summation by n :

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{k=i}^j 1 
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n (j-i+1) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=i}^n j - i \sum_{j=i}^n 1 + \sum_{j=i}^n1 \right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=i}^n j  -i(n-i+1)+ (n-i+1)\right)
\end{align}$$

I don't know what to do from there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}(j-i+1)&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}(n-i-j+1)\\&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n-i+2}{2}\\&=&\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\binom{i}{2}\\&=&\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\end{eqnarray*}$$
by a [well-known identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk).

Comment: My book gives me this final answer = (n3 +3n2 +2n) / 6

Comment: @AlexB: then, probably, your book defines $\sum_{k=i}^{j}1$ for $i>j$ in a different way.

Comment: The second summation starts at $j=i$ and not $j=1$ and the result in the book is correct.

Comment: @AlexB: sorry, I misread an index. Now fixed.

Comment: I now understand the power of the Iverson bracket.

Answer (score 1):

> Using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), we see that:
>   $$\sum_{x=a}^b f(x)=\sum_x f(x)[a\le x\le b]$$
>   where $x$ ranges over all integers on the RHS. Another feature of the Iverson bracket is, for any statements $P$ and $Q$, we have $[P\text{ and }Q]=[P][Q]$. This can be used to simplify complicated sums in which the ranges of the summation signs depend on each other.

Using the Iverson bracket, we see your sum is:
$$\sum_{i,j,k}[1\le i\le k\le j\le n]$$
Noting that $a\le b$ is the same as $a<b+1$, when working with the integers, we see that the sum is the same as:
$$\sum_{i,j,k}[1\le i<k+1<j+2\le n+2]$$
In other words, we want to find the number of ways of choosing three distinct numbers ($i$, $k+1$, and $j+2$) from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n+2\}$. In other words, we're choosing three objects out of $n+2$ objects. This is:
$$\binom{n+2}3$$

Comment: beautiful and simple.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{k=i}^j 1
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^j\sum_{k=1}^k1
&&(1\le i\le k\le j\le n)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^j\binom k1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom {j+1}2\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {n+2}3}
\end{align}$$