# Proving $\sum_\limits{k=0}^n \binom {k+m} {k} = \binom {m+n+1} {n}$ by induction.

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n \binom {k+m} {k} = \binom {m+n+1} {n}$, where $n, m \in \Bbb N$.

I missed two lectures due to illness and now have this for homework. I am completely out of my depth, mostly due to there being  a second variable to deal with.

Comment: Well, first off, you can't start $k$ from $0$ if you then divide by it. Also, is $m$ a constant?

Comment: It's a copy paste of what's on the sheet, double checked it. I would assume m to be a constant. I am fairly new to the topic, but there is nothing determining any behavior for m.

Comment: Does this mean I should simply state that the claim is false due to the division by 0?

Comment: Well, that's rather perplexing. Also, the statement is false for $n=1$, and skipping the $k=0$ term.

Comment: Oh lord, they were binomials. Ok, _now_ it makes sense!

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando: The OP has no idea what he is writing there: those are binomial coefficients (therefore without fraction line), not fractions.

Comment: Skipping those lectures really did hurt, didn't it? ;)

Comment: Well, this will be a fun semester.. I didn't chose to, I was simply too sick to go.

Comment: Cheer up! Look up the definition for the binomial, and you'll see that the induction is actually doable!

Comment: Will do. One thing: Is there anything special about how to deal with the constant in this case? For some reason it really put me off.

Comment: Nop, just treat it like any ol' number. That's the trick with most of the ugly looking things in maths: just don't look at them, until you've grown confident and they don't look so scary anymore.

In fact, you can do the very same proof and just write, say, 17 instead of m, and it'll probably work the same.

Comment: In that case, thank you very much. I might pester you again later, but for now I have a lead to work with!

Comment: You’ll find several proofs in answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk-a-k-a-hockey-stick-ident) (and the one of which it was already a duplicate); [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/833460/12042) is by induction.

Comment: I don't claim to be certain of this, but I don't see how those overlap. Then again, I'm a total noob so I will trust your judgment.

Comment: MathJax tip: use `\sum_{k=0}` instead of `\sum\limits{k=0}`