# Proof for this binomial coefficient's equation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> For $k, l \in \mathbb N$
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^l\binom{i+j}i=\binom{k+l+2}{k+1}-1$$
>   How can I prove this?

I thought some ideas with Pascal's triangle, counting paths on the grid and simple deformation of the formula.

It can be checked [here (wolframalpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(i+%3D+0,+k,+sum(j+%3D+0,+l,+C(i+%2B+j,+i)))).

If the proof is difficult, please let me know the main idea.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I got [the great and short proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3036497/625590) using Hockey-stick identity by Anubhab Ghosal, but because of this form, I could also get the [Robert Z's specialized answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3036508/625590).
Then I don't think it is fully duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$ (a.k.a. Hockey-Stick Identity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-limits-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk-a-k-a-hockey-stic)

Comment: @user10354138 The double sum is related Hockey-Stick Identity but it is not a duplicate of the linked question. Moreover OP asks for a combinatorial proof (counting paths...)

Comment: @RobertZ The OP didn't ask for a *combinatorial* proof, only for a proof ("How can I prove this?" in the quote, not "How can I prove this combinatorially?").  It can be proved by applying the linked result twice, so it is a duplicate.

Comment: @user10354138 Fine. So we have a different opinion on this matter. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea about a **combinatorial proof** which is related to counting paths in a grid is a  good one!

The binomial $\binom{i+j}i$
counts the paths on the grid from $(0,0)$ to $(i,j)$ moving only right or up. So the double sum 
$$\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^l\binom{i+j}i-1$$
counts the number of all such paths from $(0,0)$ to any vertex inside the rectangle $(0,k)\times (0,l)$ different from $(0,0)$.

Now consider the paths from $(0,0)$ to $(k+1,l+1)$ different from $$(0,0)\to (0,l+1)\to (k+1,l+1)\quad\text{and}\quad
(0,0)\to (k+1,0)\to (k+1,l+1)$$ which are
$$\binom{k+l+2}{k+1}-2.$$

Now any path of the first kind can be completed to a path of the second kind by changing direction, going to the boundary of the rectangle 
$(0,k+1)\times(0,l+1)$ and then moving to the corner $(k+1,l+1)$ along the side.

Is this a bijection between the first set of paths and the second one?

Answer (score 5):

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^l\binom{i+j}i=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=i}^{i+l}\binom{j}i=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{i+l+1}{i+1} \ ^{[1]}$$

$$=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{i+l+1}{l}=\sum_{i=l}^{k+l+1}\binom{i}{l}−1=\binom{k+l+2}{k+1}-1\ ^{[1]}$$

[1. Hockey-Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}
> {i + j \choose i} = {k + \ell + 2 \choose k + 1} - 1:\ {\LARGE ?}.\qquad k, \ell \in \mathbb{N}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}
{i + j \choose i}} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}{i + j \choose j} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}{-i - 1 \choose j}
\pars{-1}^{\,j}
\\[5mm] = &\ 
\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}\pars{-1}^{\,j}
\bracks{z^{\, j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-i - 1} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}\pars{-1}^{\,j}
\bracks{z^{0}}{1 \over z^{\, j}}\,\pars{1 + z}^{-i - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\pars{1 \over 1 + z}^{i + 1}
\sum_{j = 0}^{\ell}\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{\,j}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\braces{{1 \over 1 + z}\,
{\bracks{1/\pars{1 + z}}^{k + 1} - 1 \over 1/\pars{1 + z} - 1}}
\braces{{\pars{-1/z}^{\ell + 1} - 1 \over -1/z - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\braces{%
{1 - \pars{1 + z}^{k + 1} \over -z}
\,{1 \over \pars{1 + z}^{k + 1}}}
\braces{{\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1} - z^{\ell + 1} \over -1 - z}\,{z \over z^{\ell + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{\ell + 1}}\braces{1 - {1 \over \pars{1 + z}^{k + 1}}}
\braces{z^{\ell + 1} + \pars{-1}^{\ell} \over 1 + z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{\ell}\bracks{z^{\ell + 1}}
\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{-1} - \pars{1 + z}^{-k - 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{\ell}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1} - {-k - 2 \choose \ell + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-1  - \pars{-1}^{\ell}\,{-\bracks{-k - 2} + \bracks{\ell + 1} - 1 \choose \ell + 1}\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-1 + { k + \ell + 2 \choose \ell + 1} =
\bbx{{k + \ell + 2 \choose k + 1} - 1}
\end{align}