# How can I prove this Formula (about sum of r-combination of multiset)?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

This is a formula about the binomial.I am so confused to prove it by combination way.

$${\sum _{r=0}^{k}{\binom {n+r-1}{r}}={\binom {n+k}{k}}}$$
[Formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%7B%5Csum%20_%7Br%3D0%7D%5E%7Bk%7D%7B%5Cbinom%20%7Bn+r-1%7D%7Br%7D%7D%3D%7B%5Cbinom%20%7Bn+k%7D%7Bk%7D%7D%7D)

Comment: You mean, how to prove it __combinatorially__? (Instead of say, algebraically)

Comment: @JMoravitz Is it exactly the same as the other one? Here $r$ in $\binom{n + r - 1}{r}$ varies, but in the other one, $k$ in $\binom t k$ does not.

Comment: @M.Vinay Yes, it is.  The hockey stick identity can be written such that it travels diagonally down to the left ending with a sharp right turn along Paschal's triangle or as is the case here, diagonally down to the right with a sharp left at the end.  The only steps to transform from the one version to the other is to remember that $\binom{t}{k} = \binom{t}{t-k}$ and re-index.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-limits-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk-a-k-a-hockey-stic?noredirect=1&lq=1) was also closed as duplicate of the one I linked already for same reason.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for clearing that up.