# Proving Identity of Combination

Tags: combinatorics

The lecturer had given two questions of proving that are
$$\binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+...+\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}\text{for }n\geq{r}\geq{1}   $$
$$\binom{r}{0}+\binom{r+1}{1}+...+\binom{r+k}{k}=\binom{r+k+1}{k}\text{for }r,k\geq{1}$$

I tried to use the induction to prove these two identites but the lecturer said these two proving questions should be related to the identity which is
$$\binom{m+n}{r}=\binom{m}{0}\binom{n}{r}+...+\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{0}$$

Comment: Find $$\binom{n+1}{r+1}-\binom nr$$  and $$\binom{r+k+1}k-\binom{r+k}k$$

Comment: I said already I used these two and by using induction to prove the questions but the lecturer said to me the questions should be related to the Vandermonde identity.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with proving them by induction. They can also be proved combinatorially without too much difficulty. For more on the first one see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74844/induction-proof-concerning-a-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-j-mn-binomj/74857#74857) and answers. The second is equivalent to the first via the symmetry of the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given

$\displaystyle \binom{r}{0}+\binom{r+1}{1}+\binom{r+2}{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot +\binom{r+k}{k} = \binom{r+k+1}{k}\;,$ where $r,k\geq 1$

Now Using The formula of $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-1}$ on $\bf{L.H.S\;}$

We can Write $\bf{L.H.S}$ as

$\displaystyle \binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+2}{r}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot +\binom{r+k}{r}$

Coeff. of $x^r$ in $\displaystyle \left\{(1+x)^r+(1+x)^{r+1}+(1+x)^{r+2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot +(1+x)^{r+k}\right\} = \frac{(1+x)^{r+k+1}-(1+x)^{r}}{(1+x)-1}$

So Coeff. of $x^{r+1}$ in $\displaystyle \left\{(1+x)^{r+k+1}-(1+x)^{r}\right\} = \binom{r+k+1}{r+1} = \binom{r+k+1}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The coefficient of $x^r,y^r$ in $$\sum_{s=0}^k(x+y)^{r+s}$$ which is a Geometric Series,

then set $x=1$ and $y=1$ one by one

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $\displaystyle \binom{r}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+2}{r}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot +\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}\;,$

Where $n\geq r \geq 1.$

Coefficeint of $x^r$ in

$\displaystyle \left\{(1+x)^{r}+(1+x)^{r+1}+(1+x)^{r+1}\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot+(1+x)^{n}\right\} = \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^r}{(1+x)-1}=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^r}{x}$

(Using the formula $\displaystyle \left (r+r^2+..............+r^{n} = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1} \right)$

So Coeff. of $x^{r}$ in $\displaystyle \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^r}{x}$

So Coeff. of $x^{r+1}$ in $\displaystyle (1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^r = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$